# using clusterApply with unknown number of arguments

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cluster-computing

I want to be able to generalise the behavior of `clusterApply()` so that I can parallelise functions with different number of arguments.

Normally, I use `clusterApply()` like this:

```
clusterApply(cl=cl,seq_len(nsim),FUN=runsim,arg1,arg2,arg3)
```

But what if I don't know how many arguments function runsim has? I was thinking of using `do.call("runsim",listofArguments)`, but I don't know if I can use it inside of `clusterApply`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could use `do.call(clusterApply, listofArguments)`.

Comment: sorry, I was wrong. It doesn't work for me. do.call("clusterApply",list(cl=cl,seq_len(nsim),runSim,listofArguments))

Comment: The problem reduces to the question of how to handle a nested do.call inside another do.call. do.call("ClusterApply",list(...,do.call("runsim",listoA)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue seems to be the fact that `do.call` wants the function (or name thereof) as first argument while `clusterApply`, like all functions from the `apply` family, passes the iterated over object as the first argument to the function it calls. Consequently one solution could be:

```
clusterApply(cl=cl,seq_len(nsim),FUN=function(x) do.call(rumsim, args = list(...)))
```

`...` can now be filled with whatever different arguments there are including the possibility to hand over `x` (i.e., the slice of the iterated over object, in this case the simulation number).

I do not see the need to also wrap `clusterApply` into `do.call` as you know which function to call (`clusterApply`).